# Отключение в Wordpress всех rss комментариев и rss рассылок

Tags: wordpress, rss

Отключил в Вордпресс все RSS установив плагин `Disable RSS` (Сначала делал в ручную, но плагин по сути делает тоже самое). Возникла проблема в следующем, генерируются от куда то записи вот такого вида, учитывая, что в файле `header.php` где весь `<head>` я такого не писал. 
От куда оно генерируется, как мне это отключить? Кто то сталкивался с подобным?

```
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://site.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd">
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://site.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось всё просто, добавить функции в function.php:

```
remove_action ('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
```